# How to repair it

Tags: c, file, curl

My program should download all files from URLs which are in file *links.txt*. The last line in this file is: end.
I haven't idea what i'm doing wrong but I haven't any warnings after compile but when I run my program I get core dump fault. Have anyone any suggestions? The file I can read properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

int main() { 

  CURL *curl;
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  FILE *fp;
  FILE *fl;
  fl=fopen("links.txt", "r");
  char url[1000];
  fgets(url, 1000, fl);
  while(strcmp(url,"end")!=0) {

      char *name=strstr(url, "http");
      name = name+7;

      fp = fopen(name,"wb");
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
      curl_easy_perform(curl);

      fclose(fp);

      fgets(url, 1000, fl);

    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);   
    fclose(fl);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(strcmp(url,"end")!=0) {` strcmp will **always** return a nonzero value because fgets() returns the string with the '\n' still attached. So the final `fp = fopen(name,"wb");` will fail because it ties to open the file named "end\n". Asko: you chould check the return value from fopen() it can fail if the file happens to not exist.

Comment: can you try using `wget`

Comment: Unfortunatelly I couldn't use wget because it is too easy

Comment: @wildplasser I forgot write that the last line in file links.txt is: end

Comment: And all files from URLs in links.txt exist - I check it

Comment: Lean how to use a debugger.

Comment: @wildplasser +1, and this won't try to `fopen()` a file named `"end\n"`. `strstr()` is going to return `NULL` on the failure to find `"http"` (which isn't present in `"end\n"`, obviously). Thus the code will attempt `fopen(NULL, "wb")`. Nor, as you mentioned, is there any check the `fopen` on *valid* lines succeeded. It doesn't create directory paths. Ex: stripped of the 7-char http preamble, this will try, and fail, to open `"mysite.com/path/to/file.txt"`. In short, near-all of the filename management in this is wrong, mostly because *there is none*.

Comment: @Virgin: no, the last line in the file is **not** "end", it is "end\n", so the strcmp() will not return zero.